# Como obtener un solo registro de un JOIN entre 2 tablas?

Tags: sql, postgresql

sucede que tengo 2 tablas. Una es la tabla "principal" y otra tabla donde se guardan datos según lo que se haya registrado en la tabla 1.
La tabla 1 solo tendrá un registro, mientras que la tabla 2 puede tener 2 o mas registros que dependen del registro que se hizo en la tabla 1.

Al realizar el JOIN se obtienen la cantidad de registros que hayan en la tabla 2, es decir, se repiten los registros de la tabla 1.

Tengo parte de la solucion, y fue usando la funcion de agregacion **SUM(colum_name_TABLE2)**, y agrupandolos por el ID de la tabla 1. Pero, en una de las columnas de la tabla 2 el valor siempre sera diferente, pues corresponde al numero de factura generado por cada abono que haya hecho al registro principal de la tabla 1... Al final necesito mostrar, la suma de una de las columnas de la tabla 2, y los distintos numeros de factura que estan ubicados en otra columna de la misma tabla 2.

Como puedo hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No he utilizado Postgresql, pero he realizado algo similar muchas veces en MSSQL, creo que la solución a tu problema sería concatenar las facturas separandolas por comas, así podrías mostrar como resultados la suma de una de las columnas, y las facturas separadas por comas.
Aquí dejo un ejemplo que encontré en postgres.

[Concatenar con group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query)

Espero ser de ayuda.

Comment: Ya lo habia solucionado hace dias atras... Sin embargo diste la respuesta correcta. Gracias por ayudar!